# Space converted from Convert.ToChar(0) cannot be trimmed

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to achieve a status flag in an object which initially start from enum

```
Public Enum Status
    Enabled = 89
    Disabled = 78
    Unknown = 0
End Enum

Public Sub Convert()
    'Something
    Output.status = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Status.Unknown)).ToString().Trim()
End Sub
```

While Enabled/Disabled works like a champ with their output = Y/N, but the 'Unknown' status return `" "` which is not able to be trimmed, it then became `\u0000` after `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer`

I cannot search for the reason/solution on Google, may I know why is that and how can I get the empty string as expected?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It actually seems a little strange to have an enum containing ASCII values to be converted to characters....can you explain a little context, what you need this for and how `Output.status` is further processed? Especially, you serialize it, so what do you expect to happen at deserializing the trimmed value?

Comment: @RenéVogt I dont really know what is happening when deserializing because it is a requirement from the vendor who handle the client side, I use enum to represent status flag because our system contains lots of this kind of flag and I dont want the following programmer confused about them. (Y may represent enabled or deleted or isHidden etc, dont ask me why because I wanna know too lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `0` to a char you get `'\0'`, a binary zero. It seems you want a white space character instead, which is `32` (`0x20`).

So you could declare your `Status.Unkown` as 32

```
Public Enum Status
    Enabled = 89
    Disabled = 78
    Unknown = 32 // white space
End Enum
```

or need an extra treatment at your string conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much! May I know if there is a way to get an empty string?

Comment: @ZayLau if you use the `32` approach the final string should be empty after the trim.